# History of Tarski's problems on free groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lo.logic, ho.history-overview, free-groups

As is known, Tarski posed his questions about first-order theories of non-abelian free groups around 1945. However, the questions were not published in his papers or books.

What is the original published source of reliable information about posing Tarski's problems on free groups? When exactly had Tarski posed these questions at first time? Did it happen at some seminar or conference?

Comment: Steve Givant did quite a bit of work with Tarski; you might ask him.

Answer (score 8):

Tarski presented these problems at the Bicentennial Conference on Problems of Mathematios at Princeton, on december 1946. There's a relatively recent exposition of the material by Hourya Sinaceur:

[Address at the Princeton University Bicentennial Conference on Problems of Mathematics (December 17-19, 1946)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/421074) *The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic Vol. 6, No. 1 (Mar., 2000), pp. 1-44*

No notes of the conference were published at the time. If he wrote anything else about this before 1946, or shortly after, it most likely remained unpublished (perhaps you can find something in his collected works).

Comment: Where exactly in this paper it is claimed that Tarski presented the free groups problems at the Bicentennial Conference on december 1946?

Comment: I don't think he made his conjectures *directly* about free groups back then, but about decidability and "elementary theories" of more general algebraic structures. To put it on perspective, decidability of elementary abelian groups had been proven just a few years before the talk at Princeton. That would explain why neither Kharlampovich & Myasnikov or Sela make reference to any paper by Tarski in their solution to the problem.

Comment: The relevant part of the paper would be section B1, Tarki's original notes for the conference, pages 22 to 27, particularly page 27 (28 in the pdf).

Comment: As I see in Section B1, Tarski dicussed decidability problems for some theories of groups, but nothing about free groups. Also, one of Tarski's problems was not about decidability, but about elementary equivalence of all
free non-abelian groups. It seems, this kind of problems wasn't discussed in his talk.

Answer (score 5):

Why did I guess that Tarski's problems 
about first-order theories of non-abelian free groups
were not published in his papers or books, and he posed
the problems around 1945? Here are the reasons of that:

$\bullet$ 
In the papers of Kharlampovich-Myasnikov
[J. Algebra  302  (2006),  no. 2, 451-552]
and Sela 
[Geom. Funct. Anal.  16  (2006), no. 3, 707-730]
with solutions of Tarski's problems
there is no references to his publications;

$\bullet$ 
In the Kharlampovich-Myasnikov paper it is written that
the Tarski's conjectures were formulated around 1945;

$\bullet$ 
Lyndon in his paper [Problems in combinatorial group theory, 
in: Combinatorial group theory and topology, Ann. Math. Stud., Princeton Univ. Press,
1987] formulated the problem on elementary equivalence of all non-abelian free groups
and called it a folklore problem of Alfred Tarski.

I checked Tarski's papers and books and now I know that his problems
on the elementary theory of free groups had been formulated in some of his
publications; so these problems were not `folklore'.
Also, it seems the problems had been posed not around 1945 but later.

The first Tarski's publication where the decision problem for 
the theory of non-abelian free groups was mentioned
is the Tarski's book [Undecidable theories, North-Holland, 1953]. On p. 77 he informed that
he stated his result of undecidability of the elementary theory of groups
at a conference in Princeton in December, 1946.
On p. 85, he wrote: 'For many extensions of the elementary theory of
groups, e.g. for elementary theories of finite groups and non-Abelian free groups, 
the decision problem remains open'.
Note that it was not a conjecture on decidability of the elementary theory
of non-abelian free groups;  he just said that it was not known whether
the theory is decidable or not. Clearly, the question had been raised
between 1945 and 1953, and I don't know when exactly.

In that Tarski's book the problem of elementary equivalence 
of all non-abelian free groups was not mentioned.
First time it was published in Vaught's abstract
[Bull. AMS, 61 (1955), N 2, 173-174], where he formulated his theorem implying
that standard embeddings of free groups of infinite rank are elementary and wrote:
'These investigations arose from a still unresolved conjecture of Tarski's 
that any two free groups with at least two generators are arithmetically equivalent'.
That theorem was a result from Chapter 3 of Vaught's PhD thesis (Berkeley, 1954),
the supervisor of which was Tarski.
Later the Vaught's theorem and the Tarski's conjecture were published in Tarski-Vaught's paper
[Compositio Math.  13 (1957), 81-102]; see pages 82 and 98.
Also, in the introduction of the paper it is written that the decision problem for the elementary theory of
free non-abelian groups is a closely related open problem.